# VS 2015 crashes when loading project

Tags: visual-studio-2015

Last week my VS2015 started acting up. It would crash each time I loaded a project, and give me a null exception dialog when creating a project.
I tried to repair and restore to previous restore point. Nothing helped. Finally I uninstalled and reinstalled it, then it worked. 
Today it happened again - crash each time I load a project (C# project with TS files).

in the event log I see this. `.GlobalServiceProvider" could not be satisfied`. Any suggestion of what to do to get VS working again. ?

Thanks in advance

Jesper

```
Application: devenv.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The application requested process termination through System.Environment.FailFast(string message).
Message: Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: Import "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.LegacyContentTypeSource.GlobalServiceProvider" could not be satisfied. ---> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.CompositionFailedException: Value exported from "Microsoft.VisualStudio.ComponentModelHost.VsComponentModelHostExporter.Provider" cannot be assigned to import site "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Editor.Implementation.LegacyContentTypeSource.GlobalServiceProvider".
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.ThrowIfExportedValueIsNotAssignableToImport(RuntimeImport import, RuntimeExport export, Object exportedValue)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportSite(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.SatisfyImports()
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.SatisfyImports()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.SatisfyImmediateImports()
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToStateTransitively(PartLifecycleState requiredState, HashSet`1 visitedNodes)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToStateTransitively(PartLifecycleState requiredState, HashSet`1 visitedNodes)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()
...
```

Comment: have you installed the Update 2? If not, do it and install the update

Comment: I did install update 2. And I just did a repair (again - took couple of hours) and still crashes when the project is loaded.

Comment: I uninstalled all plugins and extensions. Then re-installed only TS. and now I'm able load the TS project